# DateTime AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am using the below AMPScript for getting the date and time -

If the "Appoint_DateTime" is set to 7/18/2016 4:00 PM, @FinalTime comes out as 4:0
I want it as 4:00 PM

How do I do it?

```
%%[
var @appoint, @Year, @Month, @Day, @FinalDate, @Hour, @Minute, @FinalTime, @test 
set @appoint = AttributeValue("Appoint_DateTime") 
set @test = DateParse(@appoint) 
set @Year = Datepart(Appoint_DateTime,"Y") 
set @Month = Datepart(Appoint_DateTime,"M") 
set @Day = Datepart(Appoint_DateTime,"D") 
set @FinalDate = CONCAT(@Month,"/",@Day,"/",@Year) 
set @Hour = Datepart(Appoint_DateTime,"H") 
set @Minute = Datepart(Appoint_DateTime,"MI") 
set @FinalTime = CONCAT(@Hour,":",@Minute)
]%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this using the [format()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/string/Format.html) function.

```
%%[
var @appoint, @finalTime
set @appoint = AttributeValue("Appoint_DateTime") 
set @finalTime = format(@appoint,"hh:mm tt")

]%%

@appoint: %%=v(@appoint)=%%
<br>@finalTime: %%=v(@finalTime)=%%
```